# 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from REGEXP with CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My SQL table structure looks like this

| id | available_sizes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | S,M,L |
| 2 | L,XL |
| 3 | Small,Large |
| 4 | 30,32,33 |

Here I want to filter all IDs which consist of M or L sizes. I tried this operation with CONCAT and REGEXP, I tried this statement with PHP

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(",", available_sizes, ",") REGEXP ",(?|?),"');

$param1 = "M";
$param2 = "L";

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $param1, $param2);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Bt it shows an error: 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp query.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match with `REGEXP` against `\b(M|L)\b`.  Build the entire alternation in PHP and then bind it to a placeholder in the MySQL query:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE available_sizes REGEXP ?");
$params = array("M", "L");
$regex = "[[:<:]](" . implode("|", $params) . ")[[:>:]]";

$stmt->bind_param("s", $regex);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Note: On MySQL 8+, use the above with the following minor change:

```
$regex = "\\b(" . implode("|", $params) . ")\\b";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because it does not say in which table in the REGEXP part.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE yourcolumn REGEXP your expression;
```